# Taking input and output to file using pointer array

Tags: arrays, c, file, pointers

Here, the array pointer `name[i]` is not not working and I can't figure out how to change the pointer or the array to make it work. There was no compiler error/warning but the console terminal showed a negative return value and `printf()` was not working.

Also, the output file was created but it was empty: nothing was written into it.

I guess there's some problem with the `fscanf()` action of taking string input from file.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fr, *fw;
    fr = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    float wt[10], ht[10], bmi[10];
    char *name[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fr, "%s\t%f\t%f", &name[i], &wt[i], &ht[i]);
        bmi[i] = wt[i] / pow(ht[i], 2);
    }
    printf("%s", name[2]);
    fw = fopen("bmi.txt", "w");
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        fprintf(fw, "%s\t%f\n", name[j], bmi[j]);
    }
    fclose(fr);
    fclose(fw);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a more elaborate description than "is not working"?

Comment: Also, what is the content of the file?

Comment: `char* name[5];` is an array of 5 pointers, each of them pointing nowhere. Also `&name[i]` is not a pointer to char, it's a pointer to a pointer to char, but %s needs a pointer to char. Didn't you get compiler warnings?

Comment: Did your scan work? I.e. is the return value (not the scanned input) of `fscanf()` as you expect it? What do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not assume that the file size is 5. You should dynamically allocate memory to the name variable like so:

```
int length;
fseek(filename, 0, SEEK_END);
length = ftell(filename);
name = malloc(length);
fread(name, 1, length, filename);
```